# Absolute Palette in GnuPlot

Tags: gnuplot

What I'm doing is scatterplotting the atoms in molecules. Different colors for different elements with the palette defined just like above, but if I don't have one of those elements in the molecule, Gnuplot just rescales the whole color scheme and the molecule looks like crap.

Is there a way I can nail down 1 to be a color, 2 to be a color, 3 to be a color etc., without having to redefine the cbrange or palette for every molecule I plot? In other words, whether or not any one of those integers exist in the plot or not.

Comment: "the palette defined just like above"   Where?!? Please show the palette definition and plot command!

Answer (score 0):

Set `maxcolors` to the number of different atoms. Specify the colors with `set palette defined`. Avoid rescaling by setting `cbrange`.

The following script has colors for atom types 1 to 6, but the data contains only atom types 1 to 4  which are displayed correctly:

```
set palette maxcolors 6
set palette defined (1 "#ff0000", 2 "#00ff00", 3 "#0000ff", \
                     4 "#ffff00", 5 "#00ffff", 6 "#ff00ff" )
set cbrange [0.5:6.5]


set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:2]

plot "-" notitle ls 5 ps 3 lc palette         
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 3
4 1 4
```

[image: colors set independent from data range]

The colorbox can be removed with `unset colorbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `linecolor variable` to use a value from the data file as linetype:

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb "#ff0000"
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#00ff00"
set linetype 3 lc rgb "#0000ff"

$data << EOD
1 3 1
2 2 2
3 1 3
EOD
plot $data using 1:2:3 linecolor variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting maxcolors did the trick.  Thanks for looking out even when I forgot to post the code!

Comment: Please don't add answers as comments. But [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the correct answer instead.